# Finding the SObjectType from the SObjectField

Tags: metadata, describesobject, sobjecttype, sobjectfield

As part of the implementation of an API, I would like to be able to find the `SObjectType` from the `SObjectField`:

```
public class MyClass {
    // Fields are from various SObjects
    public void myMethod(SObjectField[] fs) {
        for (SObjectField f : fs) {
            DescribeFieldResult dfr = f.getDescribe();
            SObjectType t = ...;
            ...;
        }
    }
}
```

but even in the describe results it does not appear to be present. Am I missing something?

Comment: A similar question that includes some brute force approaches for finding a matching SObjectType - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/32528/102

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible currently. There's no methods on Schema.SObjectField of Schema.DescribeFieldResult that link back to the SObjectType that field belongs to.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little old, but I was searching how to solve this problem and I couldn't find anything useful. This is how I solved it:

```
Type myObjectType = MyObject__c.myField__c.class;
String myObjectName = myObjectType.toString(); // You can use getName() as well
```

That code will give you the `Type` of `MyObject__c` class. Then you can use all the methods for `Type` class in Apex like `toString()` or `getName()` to get the String name of `MyObject__c`.

Please check [Salesforce Type Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) for more info.

Comment: although this works (and is clever), OP has a variable of type `Schema.SObjectField` and I don't see how one gets from `Account.Website` to `Account.Website.class` to make your scheme work

Answer (score 2):

## Update Spring '23 v57.0

This is now possible using the `getSObjectType()` method.

e.g.

```
Schema.SObjectField myField = My_Object__c.My_Field__c;

Assert.areEqual(myField.getDescribe().getSObjectType(), My_Object__c.SObjectType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the documentation for the DescribeFieldResult class, maybe it will help

getReferenceTo()

> Returns a list of Schema.sObjectType objects for the parent objects of
>   this field. If the isNamePointing method returns true, there is more
>   than one entry in the list, otherwise there is only one

Signature
     public List `<Schema.sObjectType>` getReferenceTo()

Return Value
Type: `List<Schema.sObjectType>`

[LINK](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm)

Comment: I'm afraid that relates to the type of the object referenced by the field not the type of the object containing the field. But thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Yup, you are correct. Sorry about that..