# How to get SObjectType for a given Schema.SObjectField?

Tags: apex, schema

I have

```
Schema.SObjectField field = MyObject__c.myField__c;
Schema.SObjectType objectType = getTypeOf(field);
```

how would `getTypeOfField()` need to look like for this to be true?

```
System.assertEquals(MyObject__c.SObjectType, objectType);
```

Comment: Looks like I added a #duplicate of the unanswered http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32528/how-to-get-sobjecttype-for-a-given-schema-sobjectfield

Comment: Looks like you added a #duplicate of the answered [salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/29911/...](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/29911/320) ;-) it's a no-go even with `getReferenceTo()`

Comment: I think in 2 years someone might have found a solution to this. So please don't close ;-)

Comment: I agree with @user320 it's a no go, just been racking my brain on this one also, the methods of SObjectFieldDescribe just don't provide any indiction, best i could suggest is if you know your always going to be passing a field from a known subset of custom objects is to build a map (via the fields.getMap()) internally and store it statically.

Comment: Does it have to be a `Schema.SObjectField`? If you could start passing fieldsets around you might gain some flexibility (admin able to modify the page without the help of a developer) and the FieldSet class does have the `getSobjectType()`: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fieldsets_describe.htm#apex_Schema_FieldSet_methods

Comment: Someone has posted an Idea to address this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E3KnQAK

Comment: Will be finally solvable when this becomes GA https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_getsobjecttype.htm&type=5&release=242

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Spring 23, this can be solved using this method `getSObjectType()` on class `DescribeFieldResult`

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = someField.getDescribe();
Schema.sObjectType sourceType = fieldDescribe.getSObjectType();

or, in one line

Schema.sObjectType sourceType = someField.getDescribe().getSObjectType();

e.g.

Assert.areEqual(Account.SObjectType,Account.Website.getDescribe().getSObjectType());
```

Comment: Spring '23 release note for [Discover the Source SObject of a DescribeFieldResult Instance](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_getsobjecttype.htm&type=5&release=242)

Answer (score 11):

I may be missing the boat here but why not a method based on the following?

```
// Build a map of hashcodes for each fieldDescribe taken from Schema Global Describe
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Map<Integer,Schema.SObjectType> fldHashCodeToSObjectTypeMap = new map<Integer,Schema.SObjectType>();

for (String sobjname: gd.keySet()) {
    for (Schema.SObjectField sobjField : gd.get(sObjName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
        fldHashCodeToSObjectTypeMap.put(((Object) sObjField).hashCode(),gd.get(sobjName));

}

// Then compare your sobjectField in hand by hashing it and then looking up into the map
Schema.SObjectField field0 = Account.Industry; 
Integer field0Hash = ((Object) field0).hashCode();
Schema.SObjectField field1 = Opportunity.CloseDate; 
Integer field1Hash = ((Object) field1).hashCode();

System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'field0 belongs to sobject:' + fldHashCodeToSObjectTypeMap.get(field0Hash)); 
System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'field1 belongs to sobject:' + fldHashCodeToSObjectTypeMap.get(field1Hash));
```

**Debug output yields:**

```
17:58:06.113 (1113461278)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|INFO|field0 belongs to sobject:Account
17:58:06.113 (1113547114)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|INFO|field1 belongs to sobject:Opportunity
```

Your `Util.getType(someSobjectField)` method would simply do

```
fldHashCodeToSObjectTypeMap.get((Object) someSobjectField).hashCode());
```

on some static variable instantiation of `fldHashCodeToSObjectTypeMap`

Comment: hashCode func is an interesting angle - looks good!

Comment: @bigassforce : this is what happens when one reads too many SFSE answers from smarter folks than me; odd ideas show up in my brain

Comment: I think I don't really like this because what you do is not asking a encapsulated system for an answer bu store all possible answers in a map before and than just retrieve them.

Comment: oh well.  At least your 50 pt incentive inspired me to learn something new.

Comment: Sure @crop1645 thanks for sharing your idea. It's better than leaving it unsolved. But actually I expected some Salesforce internals to tell me there is an undocumented method getSObjectType() on SObjectField ;-)

Answer (score 10):

*While I really hope there is an easier way to achieve this*, the **Tooling API** might be one candidate.

You can interrogate the [Salesforce Tooling API with an Apex library](https://github.com/bigassforce/tooling) or just use the code below by itself:

1. First specify your field name:

   ```
   //choose your field name (without suffix!)
   String fieldName = yourField.getDescribe().getName().substringBefore('__c');
   System.debug(fieldName);
   ```

   > 'Status'
2. Then obtain the **Custom Object Id** (eg 01I...) or **Table Enum** (eg Account) which it lives on:

   ```
   String query = 'SELECT TableEnumOrId From CustomField WHERE DeveloperName = \'' + fieldName + '\'';
   String endpoint = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
   endpoint += '/services/data/v29.0/tooling/query/?q=';
   endpoint += EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query, 'UTF-8');

   HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
   request.setMethod('GET');
   request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
   request.setEndpoint(endpoint);

   HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
   String tableEnumOrId = response.getBody().substringAfter('"TableEnumOrId":"').substringBefore('"');

   System.debug(tableEnumOrId);
   ```

   > '01Ib0000000CM8TEAW'
3. Finally, you can pull the API / **Developer Name** off the Custom Object definition itself:

   ```
   query = 'SELECT DeveloperName From CustomObject Where Id = \'' + tableEnumOrId + '\'';
   endpoint = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
   endpoint += '/services/data/v29.0/tooling/query/?q=';
   endpoint += EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query, 'UTF-8');

   request = new HttpRequest();
   request.setMethod('GET');
   request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
   request.setEndpoint(endpoint);

   response = new Http().send(request);
   System.debug(response.getBody());
   String customObjectName = response.getBody().substringAfter('"FullName":"').substringBefore('"');

   System.debug(customObjectName);
   ```

   > 'Schematic'
4. Use [Type.forName](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm) to get at your desired SObject, SObjectType, or DescribeSObjectResult:

   ```
   Type reflector = Type.forName('Invoice__c');
   SObject obj = (SObject)reflector.newInstance();
   SObjectType objectType = obj.getSObjectType();
   //now you can do objectType.getDescribe etc...
   ```

There are a number of caveats which would need serious 'hardening':

- you may need to truncate or append the `__c` as necessary in the Tooling API queries
- in managed context you will need to play with the namespace prefix.
- gonna be tricky if you have multiple fields with the same name!

Comment: Just wondering how this would work if i had the same field name on multiple custom objects? e.g. Total on object A and object B?

Comment: Wouldn't work, thanks for spotting! Need to query `TableEnumOrId` from CustomObject beforehand @AndrewFawcett

Answer (score 3):

These are just two additional hacks to get the information until SF finally provides a propper getter. The first is faster, the second is solid.

### Faster Approach:

SF obviously stores the information on the field internally and use it for the Error message:

> System.SObjectException: MyNamespace__MyCustomObject__c.Name does not belong to SObject type Account

I decided to simply use this information. I know it's a little fragile since we never know what they will change internally, but since we don't have any stable, lean alternative and I don't want to do API callouts for simple information like this, I decided to go this way.

```
private static final Map<String, SObjectType> SOBJECT_TYPES = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
private final SObjectField field;

public SObjectType sObjectType() {
    try {
        new Account().put(field, null);
        return Account.SObjectType;
    }
    catch (SObjectException e) {
        return SOBJECT_TYPES.get(e.getMessage().substringBefore('.'));
    }
}
```

It works for custom, standard, and namespaced types. I also did some performance testing and can say, that it takes about **twice** as long as getting the lookups parent type as we all do it sometimes something similar to this: `field.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()[0]`.

### Solid Approach:

Another approach is a roundtrip through the parent type. There we know all the child relationships, so what we need to do, is find the child relationship, that belongs to this field. And this child relationship now also knows the child's Type.

```
public SObjectType sObjectTypeStable() {
    for(ChildRelationship relationship : parentType().getDescribe().getChildRelationships()) {
        if(relationship.getField() == field) {
            return relationship.getChildSObject();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Compared to the try/catch approach it multiplies the execution time by a **factor of 10** or more (probably varies by the ChildReference's index), so I do not recommend it!

### GIST:

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/itsmebasti/4025c80cbdf4e38617a2f7dd3ac25014) contains the example class. For sure, it could be performance-optimized, but in real-world scenarios, I would not benefit from any additional caching so I skipped it.

This is how its used:

```
SObjectField field = Contact.AccountId;
SObjectType type = new FieldDescribe(field).sObjectType();
SObjectType stable = new FieldDescribe(field).sObjectTypeStable();
SObjectType parent = new FieldDescribe(field).parentType();
List<SObjectType> parents = new FieldDescribe(field).parentTypes();
```

Comment: Exceptions are super slow in Apex. Is your "Faster Approach" really that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant one of my two approaches is 10 times faster than the other (solid) approach. Sorry, if this was not clear through the description. But compared to most of the others I would say it is simpler and faster, doesn't need API callouts, doesn't need huge metadata caches or computation, and is easy to read and understand. So yes, Exceptions are slow, but there will be a tradeoff as long as SF does not provide the feature and in my subjective understanding, this is the best so far.

Comment: Nothing to apologize for, it was an honest question.

Comment: Alright, Yes, I did a bunch of tests, executing the two approaches 10.000 times in a loop and compared the results with the 'straightforward' parent type retrieval.
The fastest was the parent type with about 500ms, then the Exception with about 1000ms, and then the ChildRelationships with about 10.000ms for 10k executions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old, but I was searching how to solve this problem and I couldn't find anything useful. This is how I solved it:

```
Type myObjectType = MyObject__c.myField__c.class;
String myObjectName = myObjectType.toString(); // You can use getName() as well
```

That code will give you the Type of `MyObject__c` class. Then you can use all the methods for `Type` class in Apex like `toString()` or `getName()` to get the String name of `MyObject__c`.

Please check the [Salesforce Type Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) for more info.

Comment: This will not work when just have an instance of Schema.SObjectField instead of MyObject__c.myField__c. Remember my initial question is how to get the Schema.SObjectType for a given Schema.SObjectField.