# Is it possible to get parent SObjectType from sObjectField token?

Tags: apex, sobjecttype

Is it possible to get SObjectType dynamically from field token like `Account.Name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update Spring '23

There is now a method on the `DescribeFieldResult` called `getSObjectType()`.

This can be used to get the sObjectType from the sObjectField token.

e.g.

```
Schema.SObjectField myField = Account.Name;
Schema.SObjectType theFieldsObject = myField.getDescribe().getSObjectType();
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not<sup>*</sup>. The only method that a field token has is `getDescribe()`, and the `DescribeFieldResult` class doesn't contain any methods that return which SObject the field is for.

<sup>*: Not for all fields, at least. It is likely possible if you are working with a relationship field and use the relationship name. I don't think that approach is practical/useful though. Since you need to hardcode the field token or use an sobject token/describe to get at the field tokens/describes, you should have a better source for that information anyway.</sup>

Comment: `DescribeFieldResult.getReferenceTo()` but for field token seems to return always an empty list `Account.Name.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()`?

Comment: @gpoluch `getReferenceTo()` only returns data for relationship fields, and it gives you the parent sobject, not the sobject your field is actually on.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for explanation @Derek F.

Comment: there is [a brute force approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/105325/2602) -- I sure wish SFDC would implement the OP's rquest