# How to get a DescribeSObjectResult from a DescribeFieldResult

Tags: apex, schema

I have a function argument, `dfr`, that is of type `Schema.DescribeFieldResult`. Based off this variable, I need to find it's parent SObject and get the Describe Result for it (`Schema.DescribeSObjectResult`).

From the documentation, I see that I can get an [`SObjectField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm#apex_class_Schema_SObjectField) either via [`getController()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getController) or [`getSObjectField()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getSObjectField), but `SObjectField` seems to be a mostly useless class as it's only documented function is [`getDescribe()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm#apex_class_Schema_SObjectField) which just takes me back to the `DescribeFieldResult`. (I know that it can also be compared to other SObjectField instances, but this isn't helpful since I don't want to compare it against every field in the org).

Is there some utility function or something I haven't found yet that can at least get the SObject name, or, preferably, the `DescribeSObjectResult`, for a given `DescribeFieldResult`?

Comment: If you mean you want to find the SObjectType that an SObjectField is part of, that mechanism is missing from the API. See e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29911/finding-the-sobjecttype-from-the-sobjectfield. So in any code where you are working with these, you need to pass both values around.

Comment: Thanks... that answers in my question. Very disappointing, but should have expected it.